# correct way to use routes.rb namespace rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm trying to create a back-end area to my application, so I've created a folder named backend and `backend_controller.rb` inside it. I need the folder because the backend area will have multiple folders, so it's better-separated from my others.

my `routes.rb` looks like:

```
namespace :backend do
    get 'index'
end
```

my `backend_controller.rb`:

```
class BackendController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

But in this mode Rails will search for my `backend_controller.rb` inside the controllers folder, not in controller>backend. I've tried many variations, and I get routing errors.

So what is correct way to do that? To set the path /backend to index action instead of /backend/index?

Thanks

---

**What i've done:**
based on all answers, principally the one from *Cyril DD*

I've created the `backend_controller.rb` on the `app/controller` folder and in the sub-folder `app/controller/backend` i created the `static_pages_controller.rb` and all files looks like this:

**app/controllers/backend_controller.rb**:

```
class BackendController < ApplicationController
end
```

**app/controller/backend/static_pages_contter.rb**:

```
class Backend::StaticPagesController < BackendController
    def dashboard
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**:

```
namespace :backend do
    resource :static_pages, path: '', only: [] do
        root to:'static_pages#dashboard'
end
```

this works fine, but cause i'm newbie on rails i must ask. This is a good or a conventional way to do that? to administrate the permissions which user can see on the backend i use the `backend_controller.rb` right? and at last wy i must use `resource:` instead just `get ''`

Comment: instead of get 'index' in routes.rb define resources backends or resource backend inside namespace :backend ... depending on you requirement

Comment: if i just do that te routes are created but won't find the controller, giving the error uninitialize constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answering your question

Alright, `namespace :something` is a shorthand for `scope 'something', module: 'something', as: 'something'`

Now your declaration is very ambiguous, because you don't specify a controller. Typical declarations look like (assume you have a controller `controllers/backend/some_resources_controller.rb` and you want to generate default routes)

```
namespace :backend do
  resources :some_resources
end
```

Now what you did

```
namespace :backend
  get 'index'
end
```

is really ambiguous and I'm not surprised it doesn't do what you want. Basically you just tell rails to "look inside subfolder 'backend' and define the route 'index'". oO ? Which file/controller are we even talking about ?

What is your `backend_controller.rb` supposed to do ? Is it some kind of Control Panel ? Dashboard ? If so you're probably gonna have a lot of non-CRUD actions, but anyways you should go for the following syntax

```
namespace :backend
  # Below line of code will auto-generate the `index` for /backend/backend_controller
  resource :backend, only: [:index], path: '' do # we need " path: '' " otherwise we'll have https://xxx/backend/backend/dashboard
    # If you have non-CRUD actions, put them here !
    get 'dashboard' # https://xxx/backend/dashboard
    ...
  end
  # However, this will create URLs like "https://xxx/backend/dashboard", etc.
  # If you want to redirect https://xxx/backend/ to your backend_controller#index, use root
  root to: 'backend#index' # https://xxx/backend/
end
```

Last thing as mentionned by other guys, when you namespace a file like your Backend_controller inside `/backend/` subfolder, you must rename the class like (`/controllers/backend/backend_controller`)

```
class Backend::BackendController < ApplicationController
```

Remark : if you only have like one or two controller actions, instead of using the `resource` method, you can declare singular resources

namespace :backend do
  root to: 'backend#dashboard'
  get 'dashboard', to: 'backend#dashboard' # singular resource
end

---

#### An Example of what you may actually really want to do...

I'm not sure you are clear yourself about what you want to do. As an example, here is my architecture

Files

```
/controllers/application_controller.rb
/controllers/backend_controller.rb
/controllers/backend/static_pages_controller.rb
/controllers/backend/***.rb
```

The class `/controllers/backend_controller.rb` will not serve any action, but will override ApplicationController to tune it for backend access (but maybe you don't need to do so)

```
class BackendController < ApplicationController
  # Do you need to change user_access method ? Or any other backend-wide config ?
  # If so put this config here, otherwise leave empty
end
```

Now for every file that goes in the `/backend/` subfolder, I inherit the `backend_controller`

```
class Backend::StaticPagesController < BackendController
  def index
  end

  # Note : if your index is some kind of dashboard, instead I would declare
  def dashboard
  end
end

class Backend::SomeResourcesController < BackendController
  ...
end
```

Routes

```
namespace :backend do
  root to 'static_pages#index' # https://xxxx/backend/
  resource :static_pages, only: [:index], path: '' # https://xxxx/backend/index
  resources :some_resources
end
```

If you choose the dashboard solution in your controller, write instead :

```
namespace :backend do
  root to: static_pages#dashboard # https://xxxx/backend/
  resource :static_pages, path: '', only: [] do
    get 'dashboard' # https://xxxx/backend/dashboard
  end
  resources :some_resources
end
```

Comment: my index is gonna be like a dashboard or a admin profile anything like this. so i must have the /controllers/backend_controller.rb to routes to override the application_controller, or create an action on application_controller, correctly? and put all other controllers on backend folder changing the class

Comment: if do this way the i have the path /backend/static_pages/:static_page_id/dashboard(.:format) so i need to pass static _page_id and the path mysite.com/backend wont exist

Comment: Sorry, `resource` not `resources` ^^". Or you can keep this syntax and add the `,on: :collection`. I'm gonna make an edit.

Comment: And in order to generate exactly `https://xxx/backend/` and redirect it to your controller action, you should use `root to: 'controller_name#action'` (see my edits)

Answer (score 1):

Then it's simply

```
# routes.rb 
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :backend, shallow: true do
    resource :backend, path:''
  end
end
```

Then in your `app/controllers/backend/backend_controller.rb`, it'd look like this.

```
class Backend::BackendController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

When I use `rake routes` it shows

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
backend_backends GET    /backend(.:format)          backend/backends#index
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: From where this come Authentication Controller ?? Question has no such requirements

Comment: Seems like he was trying to do nested controllers so I gave him an example

Comment: actually i want my route looks like /backend only. i just want acces mysite.com/backend and acces the index page of backend. and the controller has to be inside app>controllers>backend> backend_controller.rb

Comment: if i do that i get the error "uninitialized constant Backend::BackendsController" and the route paths are wrong ex: 'backend/backends#create' and there is no route to index

Comment: Updated my answer to further reflect what you'd like. I recreated it on a local environment and I got the above code to work.

Comment: yes the route are there but i get the error uninitialized constant BackendController, did you try to access the route in browser?

Comment: Yes, I accessed it in browser. Three things must match, they all need to be singular in your case (I just updated my answer to reflect that). backend_controller.rb, resource :backend, and class BackendController < ... Those three lines must match.